# Make 16-bit code work in WinXP or Vista (or alternately how to find Win98 retail licenses?)

Tags: licensing, dos, 16-bit, windows-98

We have thousands of DOS programs that were all written in the 80s using 16-bit C, comprising over 1,000,000 lines of code.  Many of these programs utilize libraries that directly access the screen, drive, etc. (and we don't have the sources for these libraries).  Whenever we try to run them in Win2000 or above, even in compatibility mode, we get access violations and blue screens.

Our solution so far has been purchasing Win98SE Retail Boxes and running Win98 in a VMWare session.  The problem now is that we can't find enough non-OEM licenses (we last purchased in 2006 and need another 20 or so copies).  Our company is extremely careful about licensing, so they have no interest in buying the OEM copies (since we are not a system builder).

Our new 32-bit software won't be ready for 3 years, so unless someone knows where we can buy lots of Win98 retail boxes, I'm stuck trying to figure out how to get 16-bit software with direct system access to run in 2000/XP.  Any ideas?

Comment: Another possibility: i've heard that since MS isn't supporting Win98 any more, they've violated their own EULA, and as such the EULA doesn't apply any more, and so basically licensing doesn't apply to Win98 any more and there's nothing to stop you using it.
Having said all that, IANAL...

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/96812/using-a-printer-in-dosbox  <--- printing in DosBox.

Comment: @Chris that is just plain wrong. You are suggesting they pirate the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can make it run in linux with wine inside VMware? 
Should be quite simple to try without awaiting procurement processes and other bureaucratic overhead.

Comment: Great idea, we'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 9):

You could see if they run in DosBox ?

http://www.dosbox.com/

[Some versions of DosBox actually supports printing](https://superuser.com/questions/96812/using-a-printer-in-dosbox).

Comment: We tried that a while ago and DOSBOX didn't have printer support ... it looks like they still don't, at least according to their wiki.

Comment: Well, if it does everything else you need, how hard is it to implement? It's open source after all.

Comment: Ah, the catch-cry of the FOSS bods :-) "why don't you add the support yourself?" Well, if it's so easy for someone to do, why haven't the DosBox people done it? They presumably know the code a lot better. I suspect Lucky works in a business where they'd opt for the easiest solution.

Comment: It's very valid - if the only thing holding you back from using DosBox is print support, hire a consultant to add it; it's worth it compared to trying to dig up Win98 licenses

Comment: @Paul Betts: Plus - it's free (as in FOSS).

Comment: I mean, in the long run it won't be impossible to obtain legal copies of DOSBox, as opposed to a *flawed* business-centric model.

Comment: @Jess, I updated answer, some versions of DosBOX support printing now. Also consider vmware/virtualbox + FreeDOS. http://www.freedos.org/

Answer (score 4):

What about a system like [freedos](http://www.freedos.org/) which you could also run inside of VMWare?

Comment: Yes, FreeDOS inside vmware with parallel port emulation might work too!

Answer (score 4):

Many Microsoft licenses (including OEM and enterprise licenses; actually pretty much everything except full boxed product EULAs) allow you to ‘downgrade’ to an earlier version of the product. Vista Business and XP may both be downgraded to Win98.

> customers licensed for use of Windows Vista Enterprise are licensed for Windows Vista Business, and it can be downgraded to the Windows XP Professional, Windows 2000 Professional, Windows NT® 4.0, Windows NT 3.51, Windows 98, or Windows 95 operating system.

[General info](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4F4B3CFD-7F4E-46CB-8117-8275F7683D3F&displaylang=en&displaylang=en). Talk to MS, if you want ‘lots’, I'm sure they will be happy to sell you a bunch of licenses you can use for downgrades.

I like the FreeDOS idea too, that could save you a packet if it works.

Comment: I'll look at that downgrade option ... that might work!  We talked to MS, and they said since they stopped supporting 98 in 2006 they couldn't even provide us with any ideas on where to get it.

Comment: If that text is correct re downgrading, it appears you only need one copy of Win98SE and you can install it on as many boxes as you have Vista licenses (provided you don't use the licenses elsewhere).

Comment: @Pax: Sure. Outside of retail boxed sales, the media you own/use to install Windows is generally pretty irrelevant as long as you have the usage licences. @Lindy: I'm a bit disappointed they didn't even mention downgrades... seems like some poor salesmanship there! :-)

Comment: Since we aren't part of the Select or Open license programs, we actually have no downgrade rights (Microsoft would tell us this much ... and sent us a word doc showing which license options can be downgraded).

Comment: Good that they at least could tell how it works. @Jess. Also see http://superuser.com/questions/96812/using-a-printer-in-dosbox

Comment: Thanks, we're actually just releasing our new web-based product, and patched together our old system with e-bay licenses of Win98 from 2009 (when this was first asked) until now.  T minus 12 months until no more 98, woo hoo!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is very late, but maybe someone will find this question and use this answer.

OS/2 supports 16 bit Windows and still sells under the "eComStation" name.

www.ecomstation.com

It's possible that eComStation can run those 16 bit applications.

It won't run in VMware but it does run in Virtual Box.

Comment: Wow, good catch, I would never have thought to look there.

Comment: Wow. I only just answered this. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would work... I believe that through our MSDN subscription we have access to all sorts of "fun" things like Windows 3.11 and, yes, even Windows 98.  At least I saw that such files existed, not sure if they ere actually downloadable... something to check into perhaps.

Comment: MSDN licenses are for development machines only, though, not production.

Comment: Thats what I get for teaching... no production machines :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried asking for Win98 on Ebay?

Comment: Yep, but all the copies are either pirated or OEM.  We've sent back about 15 pirated copies so far ... it gets pretty annoying.

Comment: Hmm, that's a real prob, I've also checked my MSDN, doesn't have Win98

Comment: Even if MSDN did have it, we wouldn't be able to use it for production machines.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to run the apps remote instead? i.e. have a bunch of PCs with Win98 that are shared among users?

Comment: The main app is for data entry, so probably not.

Comment: Ok. just a thought, wasn't sure of the reqs. :)